# Is there a way to skip lines of code when condition has been met

Tags: python

newbie to python and I was creating a basic calculator with functions and variables and such, was wondering if there was a way for python to skip the two lines that you enter num1 and num2 in. Currently if you make the opr == cube/square it doesn't ask for a number to cube/square it just goes straight to the lines asking for num1 and num2.

```
opr = input("Would you like to multiply (*), Divide (/), Subtract (-), Add (+), Cube (cube) or Square (square):")
if opr == "cube":
    cube1 = int(input("Enter Number To Cube"))

elif opr == "square":
    square1 = int(input("Enter Number To Square"))

num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter another number: "))


def cube(num):
    return num * num * num


def square(num):
    return num * num


if opr == "*":
    result = float(num1) * float(num2)
if opr == "/":
    result = float(num1) / float(num2)
if opr == "-":
    result = float(num1) - float(num2)
if opr == "+":
    result = float(num1) + float(num2)
if opr == "cube":
    result = cube(cube1)
if opr == "square":
    result = square(square1)

print(result)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `if opr == 'cube': ... elif opr == 'square': .. else: num1 = ...`…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add them in a condition :

```
elif opr == "*" or opr == "-" or opr == "+" or opr == "/":
    num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter another number: "))
```

Comment: FWIW: `elif opr in '*-+/'`, or `elif opr in ('*', '-', '+', '/')`.